# Apply class to entire stylesheet

Tags: css

Will this work? I have a class applied to the main DIV and need to apply that class to the all the selectors in my stylesheet.

```
.parent-class {

    .selector1 { styles; }
    .selector2 { styles; }
    .selector3 { styles; }

}
```

instead of

```
.parent-class .selector1 { styles; }
.parent-class .selector2 { styles; }
.parent-class .selector3 { styles; }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using LESS then yes, if not then no

Comment: You can easily check it yourself.

Comment: whoa! why the negative votes. sheesh. I am beginning to use LESS and yes this stylesheet is being built with LESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with plain CSS.

You can do this with a CSS preprocessor such as LESS.

See here: http://lesscss.org/features/ (nested rules)